# Validate java object with rules in xml

Tags: java, xml, validation, object

Here is an example of my question:

1) I have an XML files where Rules for my Invoice are definded

```
<rules>
..
  <price>
   <Required>True</Required>
   <MinValue>0.1</MinValue>
  <price>
..
</rules>
```

2) I have an Invoice Object in java (important: **this should stay so (plain)**. No annotations or anything should be included.)

```
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private String details;
    private String tax;
    private String recipient;
    private double price;

    //getter and setter
```

}

3) And at least I have a Validator Object

```
public class Validator(){

    public boolean validate(String xmlfile, Invoice i) {
           //todo: Invoice i should be validated with xmlfile
    }
}
```

What I need: 
The Validator should take the XML File with the rules inside 
e.g.

```
  <price>
   <Required>True</Required>
   <MinValue>0.1</MinValue>
  <price>
```

and use that rule to validate the Invoice java object.

Are there any good frameworks I could use for that? Or tutorials? Approaches?
Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd use attributes instead of text, e.g. <price required="true" min="0.1" />

Comment: Maybe bean validation? http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/) which is implementation of JSR 303. You can write constrains in XML as below

```
<field name="x2"  ignore-annotations="true"    >  <!-- XML is stronger -->
        <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Min">
             <element name="value">2</element>
        </constraint>
    </field>
```

A complete and nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/04/14/using-hibernate-validator-to-cover-your-validation-needs)

Comment: this is not quite good. The xml file should stay as simple as possible, so companies can add there rules to it. For example <price>required</price> or <price>not required</price>

Comment: I would say add a wrapper around your XML to convert in to this XML. Writing your implementation will achieve you a little

Comment: I guess you can go for that. Since you do not want annotations and simple XML

Comment: finally I found a nice tutorial how to do it with Hibernate Validator when declaring rules in the xml file, link here: http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/04/14/using-hibernate-validator-to-cover-your-validation-needs/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this example from Apache.

```
public class ValidateExample extends Object {

     /**
       * We need a resource bundle to get our field names and errors messages 
       * from.  Note that this is not strictly required to make the Validator 
       * work, but is a good coding practice.
       */
      private static ResourceBundle apps =
          ResourceBundle.getBundle(
              "org.apache.commons.validator.example.applicationResources");

      /**
       * This is the main method that will be called to initialize the Validator, create some sample beans, and
       * run the Validator against them.
       */
     public static void main(String[] args)
         throws ValidatorException, IOException, SAXException {

          InputStream in = null;
          ValidatorResources resources = null;

          try {

              // Create a new instance of a ValidatorResource, then get a stream
              // handle on the XML file with the actions in it, and initialize the
              // resources from it.  This would normally be done by a servlet
              // run during JSP initialization or some other application-startup
              // routine.
              in = ValidateExample.class.getResourceAsStream("validator-example.xml");
              resources = new ValidatorResources(in);

          } finally {
              // Make sure we close the input stream.
              if (in != null) {
                  in.close();
             }
          }

         // Create a test bean to validate against.
         ValidateBean bean = new ValidateBean();

          // Create a validator with the ValidateBean actions for the bean
          // we're interested in.
          Validator validator = new Validator(resources, "ValidateBean");

          // Tell the validator which bean to validate against.
          validator.setParameter(Validator.BEAN_PARAM, bean);

          ValidatorResults results = null;

          // Run the validation actions against the bean.  Since all of the properties
         // are null, we expect them all to error out except for street2, which has
         // no validations (it's an optional property)

         results = validator.validate();
         printResults(bean, results, resources);

         // Now set all the required properties, but make the age a non-integer.
         // You'll notice that age will pass the required test, but fail the int
         // test.
         bean.setLastName("Tester");
         bean.setFirstName("John");
         bean.setStreet1("1 Test Street");

       bean.setCity("Testville");

      bean.setState("TE");
         bean.setPostalCode("12345");
         bean.setAge("Too Old");
         results = validator.validate();
         printResults(bean, results, resources);

         // Now only report failed fields
        validator.setOnlyReturnErrors(true);
         results = validator.validate();
         printResults(bean, results, resources);

         // Now everything should pass.
         validator.setOnlyReturnErrors(false);
         bean.setAge("123");
         results = validator.validate();
         printResults(bean, results, resources);
     }

     /**
      * Dumps out the Bean in question and the results of validating it.
      */
     public static void printResults(
         ValidateBean bean,
         ValidatorResults results,
         ValidatorResources resources) {

         boolean success = true;

         // Start by getting the form for the current locale and Bean.
         Form form = resources.getForm(Locale.getDefault(), "ValidateBean");

        System.out.println("\n\nValidating:");
         System.out.println(bean);

         // Iterate over each of the properties of the Bean which had messages.
         Iterator propertyNames = results.getPropertyNames().iterator();
         while (propertyNames.hasNext()) {
             String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.next();

             // Get the Field associated with that property in the Form
             Field field = form.getField(propertyName);

             // Look up the formatted name of the field from the Field arg0
             String prettyFieldName = apps.getString(field.getArg(0).getKey());

             // Get the result of validating the property.
             ValidatorResult result = results.getValidatorResult(propertyName);

             // Get all the actions run against the property, and iterate over their names.
             Map actionMap = result.getActionMap();
             Iterator keys = actionMap.keySet().iterator();
             while (keys.hasNext()) {
                 String actName = (String) keys.next();

                 // Get the Action for that name.
                 ValidatorAction action = resources.getValidatorAction(actName);

                 // If the result is valid, print PASSED, otherwise print FAILED
                 System.out.println(
                     propertyName
                         + "["
                         + actName
                         + "] ("
                         + (result.isValid(actName) ? "PASSED" : "FAILED")
                         + ")");

                 //If the result failed, format the Action's message against the formatted field name
                 if (!result.isValid(actName)) {
                     success = false;
                     String message = apps.getString(action.getMsg());
                     Object[] args = { prettyFieldName };
                     System.out.println(
                         "     Error message will be: "
                             + MessageFormat.format(message, args));

                 }
             }
         }
         if (success) {
             System.out.println("FORM VALIDATION PASSED");
         } else {
             System.out.println("FORM VALIDATION FAILED");
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: what kind of apache technology is this? you have a reference maybe?

Comment: I think I found what I am looking for: http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/package-summary.html#doc.Usage.validator

Answer (score 0):

I would use an implementation of **Bean Validation ([JSR 303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303))** for this use case.  The validation rules can be defined as a XML document.

Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation and it can be downloaded here:

- http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

An implementation of JSR 303 will also be included in every Java EE 6 implementation.

Comment: hi. do you have an example or reference maybe? or a tutorial, documentation where this is done so? would be great, thanks

Comment: @Delta458 - The following may help:  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html